# Extreme Transaction Slowdown on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: postgresql

I'm having a very strange issue that I cannot seem to resolve.  I have a database running on Postgresql 15, on Ubuntu 22.04.  Client is written in C#, .NET 7.0.

Development was done on Windows with no issues.  Moving the client + database over to Ubuntu causes big problems that I simply cannot find a solution for.

See below for a typical transaction log from the client.

As can see, the performance is as expected, until a point where it becomes orders of magnitude slower, from 0.2ms to 8s to run a simple query.

The client only allows one db connection in order to cancel out any other potential problems.

I have deleted the database and started from scratch before where it works for a few days, until a point where it breaks and does the same thing.  It does not get slower by the minute as everything is indexed.  Just randomly out of the blue the database "breaks".

Where do I start finding the problem ?  Any advise will be appreciated.

```
2023-05-23 16:16:52:979: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x82BdFf92B259d83382C28a2d0CF3229E0d8B0B98' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.2987ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:979: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x8810f916EEC8F5B2208f71c471594cB635cF9C75' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.2711ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:979: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0xf951E335afb289353dc249e82926178EaC7DEd78' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.1974ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:979: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0xee73323912a4e3772B74eD0ca1595a152b0ef282' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.2242ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:979: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0xe40Af8288f4B8b38e0e2e3B8e544D626Ab686c0e' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.1794ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:979: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x26e0C188Bb156923077098c35AaC652148610d18' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.1951ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:979: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x74eeD893bE1a7efCe1f18e10113bA7010011aA03' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.2954ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:980: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x800d78be7295b84CDcD9b9Ed84e1Ce21753dD4f0' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.192ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:980: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x3F8Afc39aC96337855ce1c647A1a17d29CE742Ee' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.191ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:980: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x54B50187BEcD0BBCfD52EC5d538433daB044d2A8' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.2331ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:980: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x7400070Df83ddd7388484d7abAdB546CF743A220' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.1989ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:980: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x562680a4dC50ed2f14d75BF31f494cfE0b8D10a1' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.2423ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:980: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x0F5D2fB29fb7d3CFeE444a200298f468908cC942' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.1902ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:981: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x5Ea0b5899e912e0b0BA0190DD097251DBDAa70e0' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.2281ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:981: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x1CF48E2ba68c71B3b78AEB8717719a1F4413bF2d' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.2012ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:981: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0xB63CEd2E299a1351D94611918F0cd7afaD37639d' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.1944ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:981: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0xd72e0d3e66e0BB973224FE4539648B2a0E236E99' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.1812ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:982: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x3b3ae790Df4F312e745D270119c6052904FB6790' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.1622ms
2023-05-23 16:16:52:982: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x7F6C393711bDa68A28EeDa07Cd8c2601e00D067E' : Performance Monitoring Result - 0.3005ms
2023-05-23 16:16:53:034: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0xfCAC92bCF43f1990eed01366D5ecF368Cd1DC306' : Performance Monitoring Result - 52.4968ms
2023-05-23 16:16:53:034: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x0a88BC5c32b684D467b43C06D9e0899EfEAF59Df' : Performance Monitoring Result - 52.4919ms
2023-05-23 16:16:53:034: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0xE772BBF406777d44C287c81Ea7b7F7d40cE0FC7f' : Performance Monitoring Result - 52.0753ms
2023-05-23 16:16:53:034: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x1111111254EEB25477B68fb85Ed929f73A960582' : Performance Monitoring Result - 52.0598ms
2023-05-23 16:16:53:150: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0xc64770E21Ea342B062aEc5AC4145CEa5e2Dfcf92' : Performance Monitoring Result - 167.5621ms
2023-05-23 16:16:54:063: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x9797021D4aCc56B30A77d82306d7C3f22aAbB5c8' : Performance Monitoring Result - 1080.474ms
2023-05-23 16:16:55:063: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x26f7772a97603444f72d0CDad25892Bb216B1A42' : Performance Monitoring Result - 2079.9373ms
2023-05-23 16:16:55:064: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0xb45A2DDA996C32E93B8c47098E90Ed0E7ab18E39' : Performance Monitoring Result - 2079.9953ms
2023-05-23 16:16:57:065: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x221919083D5a44eB96B1730A34D0dd568F107840' : Performance Monitoring Result - 4080.8896ms
2023-05-23 16:16:57:065: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0xd76d8B95dad4A78D88154eE1AB652FC850ef22Db' : Performance Monitoring Result - 4080.9262ms
2023-05-23 16:16:57:065: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x68d2fc29fAB6A73bE7AfB8db278680BdD60496a6' : Performance Monitoring Result - 4080.3172ms
2023-05-23 16:16:58:065: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x9507c04B10486547584C37bCBd931B2a4FeE9A41' : Performance Monitoring Result - 5080.2408ms
2023-05-23 16:16:58:065: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x648fF8e9AceB9E60d35101952E43C368Ae907936' : Performance Monitoring Result - 5080.4253ms
2023-05-23 16:16:59:066: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x3506424F91fD33084466F402d5D97f05F8e3b4AF' : Performance Monitoring Result - 6080.5515ms
2023-05-23 16:17:00:066: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x5B6122C109B78C6755486966148C1D70a50A47D7' : Performance Monitoring Result - 7080.7181ms
2023-05-23 16:17:01:067: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x4f1a5a5d258522254933a6DA9648c57Fe230D17e' : Performance Monitoring Result - 8030.9345ms
2023-05-23 16:17:02:068: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x6a9c7263bEfd305Cb07185ef7378e9F1cc51348e' : Performance Monitoring Result - 9031.3467ms
2023-05-23 16:17:02:068: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x07fF7B3D6dE68A0eC060319f3131BA72Da9acD24' : Performance Monitoring Result - 9031.315ms
2023-05-23 16:17:02:068: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0xacd750e4b2288222bE689fB33c19DD7DF34620DE' : Performance Monitoring Result - 9030.8779ms
2023-05-23 16:17:03:072: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0x238A3C4Dab875346880373c6032b2bA06F2C6381' : Performance Monitoring Result - 9918.3492ms
2023-05-23 16:17:03:072: select * from dim.addresses where address = '0xD63898cd8981c44311b934Dca4f729a7Ef715B1c' : Performance Monitoring Result - 9918.5024ms
```

Comment: You need to catch query plans of the queries, both in the fast and slow state.  You can preface the query text with "EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)", or you can use auto_explain https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html,

Comment: Something doesn't sound right about your explanation. If you only allow one client connection, how can you simultaneously issue 3-4 statements in that single connection, and measure the execution time of almost 10 seconds only one second later?

Comment: @mustaccio you are correct,  I think I allowed up to 16 connection in this instance.  However, it should not be an issue as the queries are extremely light-weight.

Comment: @jjanes I have years of experience with SQL Server and database tech.  Postgresql is a bit new to me, especially in the Linux environment.  I'm pretty sure it's not a query plan problem as the queries are just too simple to cause any such issues.  There is literally only one index and one table in the query.  There is something else going on here, since I get zero of the issues on Windows environment

Comment: It can easily choose a bad plan on a simple query under some circumstances, like if it thinks a lot of rows will match the condition.  If you are serious about using PostgreSQL, you need to learn how to get the plans.  And if you know how to get them, why not just do it?  Then we will know and not need to guess.  We aren't going to write an entire choose-your-adventure novel for you.  Answer the questions as we go along.

Comment: @jjanes thanks, this post gives a bit more detail on how to debug and also to automatically log query plans on long running queries.  I will debug and post here if I see anything

https://iamsafts.com/posts/postgres-gin-performance/